# Perl - Unable to install HTML::HTMLDoc module

Tags: html, perl, cpan

```
use HTML::HTMLDoc;    
my $htmldoc = new HTML::HTMLDoc();
$htmldoc->set_html_content(qq~<html><body>A PDF file</body></html>~);
# $htmldoc->set_input_file($filename); # alternative to use a present file from your fs
my $pdf = $htmldoc->generate_pdf();
print $pdf->to_string();
$pdf->to_file('foo.pdf');
```

I'm using ActivePerl and try to install [`HTML::HTMLDoc`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::HTMLDoc) via PPm and im getting

```
ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides HTML::HTMLDoc
```

I even tried to use Cpan install `HTML::HTMLDoc` but im getting

```
 MFRANKL/HTML-HTMLDoc-0.10.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.39)
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
 Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

How do I install the module in my Perl.

**EDITED**
[image]

Comment: You might be behind a firewall or proxy server. PPM can be configured to use a proxy server. The instructions are found here:
http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#ppm_and_proxies

Comment: @ChankeyPathak i managed to install other modules. I even managed to run the PPM interface and unable to find the HTML::HTMLDoc package. Please refer my edited question with screen shot.

Comment: See this: https://code.activestate.com/ppm/HTML-HTMLDoc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML-HTMLDoc is unavailable in PPM, because there aren't any builds for it in the package repositories.

Details: https://code.activestate.com/ppm/HTML-HTMLDoc/

Comment: Any suggestion for html to pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the [htmldoc](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php/HTMLDOC) program?  The module can't pass its tests without that installed, which is why there are no PPM packages.  ActiveState doesn't have it installed on their build servers.

I'd try manually unpacking the HTML-HTMLDoc tarball and running `perl Makefile.PL` and 
`dmake` manually to see more detail about what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I looked, HTML::HTMLDoc had terrible support for Unicode. Which is why I spent some time in 2012 ripping it out of a legacy codebase and replacing it with [PDF::WebKit](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/PHILIP/PDF-WebKit-0.91/lib/PDF/WebKit.pm) (which is a thin wrapper around [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)). I'd recommend that route.